# Exit Thread and TcpListener in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've the following problem: I created a simple HTTP server component. The server should be controlled with buttons on the GUI. I can start the server without any problems, but if I want to stop the server the whole program is killed. I think that's an error of aborting the thread but I don't know how I can solve this problem.

Here's my code:

```
public class HttpServer {
  private int port;

  public HttpServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
  }

  public void Listen() {
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    listener.Start();

    try {
      while (true) {
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        HttpProcessor processor = new HttpProcessor(client);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processor.Process));
        thread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1);
      }
    }
    catch { }

    listener.Stop();
  }
}

public class HttpProcessor {
  private TcpClient client;
  private StreamReader reader;
  private StreamWriter writer;

  public HttpProcessor(TcpClient client) {
    this.client = client;
    this.reader = null;
    this.writer = null;
  }

  public void Process() {
    reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

    ParseRequest();
    // some method calls to process the request and generate the response
    SendResponse();

    client.Close();
  }
}

public partial class MainForm : Form {
  private HttpServer server;
  private Thread servthread;

  private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    server = new HttpServer(8080);
  }

  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    servthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(server.Listen));
    servthread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }

  private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    servthread.Abort();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should probably try to close also the other objects properly, and you may think if you really need two threads.

Comment: Do *not ever* use `Thread.Abort()`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make everything "kinda" work "kinda" correctly:

1. in `HttpServer` move `listener` variable from local var to class member
2. in `HttpServer` introduce a method:

   `public void Stop()
   {
       listener.Stop();
   }`
3. Change your `Button2_Click` method to:

   `private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       server.Stop();
       servthread.Join();
   }`

PS: I assume that this is one of your first projects, so instead of writing a long post of how to do your stuff correctly, I suggested the changes that will allow you to continue your project. Bugs and architecture issues may come or may not come)
Happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not use** `Thread.Abort()`, ever! Use other means of communicating to the thread that it should stop, like a `WaitHandle` or even a `private volatile bool stopThread;` flag!

If you ever feel the need to call any other methods on a `Thread` than `Start` and `Join` you're probably doing something wrong and you should think about your design ;-)

See this: [How to: Create and Terminate Threads (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

---

On your comment about `AcceptTcpClient` being a blocking call: Yes, it is. However, as others have noted too, you could easily change your class to avoid this problem:

```
public class HttpServer {
  private int port;
  private TcpListener listener; // Make the listener an instance member

  public HttpServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    this.listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port); // Instantiate here
  }

  public void Listen() {
    listener.Start();

    try {
      while (true) {
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        HttpProcessor processor = new HttpProcessor(client);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processor.Process));
        thread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1);
      }
    }
    catch { }

    listener.Stop();
  }

  public void StopListening()
  {
    listener.Server.Close();
  }
}
```

Then, instead of `servthread.Abort();` you'd call `server.StopListening();`.

You *may* need to wrap the `listener.Stop()` line in a `try/catch` as well, but you'll have to try.

Comment: `AcceptTcpClient` is blocking call so even if you use `stopThread` `bool` in while to break. It will break while on accepting one connection after bool value set to false. Please correct me if I wrong.

Comment: I enhanced my answer. By the way, your design is pretty weird, really. Normally, the `HttpServer` class would create the thread itself, not some outside class would create a thread on the method.